# VBA SQL Query is not pulling values consistently as numeric when the data is numeric

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a excel database that I wrote VBA code to create a pricegrid by width and height based on item category. I am using 3 SQL statements to achieve this grid. One for the height, one for the Width, and one for the price for each width x height I am using SQL Queries to pull the data from the worksheet. I have additional code that fires first to transform the data into numeric or text based on column. This way the Height and Width columns will always be numbers and not numbers saved as text and the item category columns that are mixed text and numbers will be numbers stored as text. This way the StrSql Statement can pull the data without a mismatch. The problem is that while the entire column is the correct type of data on the worksheet and the sql statement is pulling the correct number type of data for one grid and then the next grid pulls the number data as string. I have checked the data in the worksheet and it is indeed converted to number and the column is formatted as a number. Some of the grids are created ok but others I get a data mismatch error. What can cause a SQL Query to pull numerical data as string only sometimes?

```
StrSql=SELECT DISTINCT [GRIDDATA$].[WIDTH] FROM [GRIDDATA$] WHERE [GRIDDATA$].[ItemCategory] = '" CAT.Fields("ItemCategory")"' ORDER BY [GRIDDATA$].[Width]
Width.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

'more code

StrSql= SELECT DISTINCT [GRIDDATA$].[Price] FROM [GRIDDATA$] WHERE [GRIDDATA$].[WIDTH] = " & Width.Fields("Width") & " AND [GRIDDATA$].[HEIGHT] = " & Height.Fields("Height") & " AND [GRIDDATA$].[ItemCategory] = '"CAT.Fields("ItemCategory")"'
PriceVal.Open strSQL, cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
```

It is only the PriceVal Query that is having the error Data Mistype error on the Width.Fields("Width"). It is sometimes pulling the number stored as a number as a string.

Below is my Prep data code

```
'Convert Width to Numbers

LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row

Set SelectR = sht.Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow)

SelectR.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("Q2"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

Comment: I tried to do a workaround that would tell if the data was numeric or string but failed epically. I created a few variables and added an if statement that if the value isNumeric then an integer variable would be used else a string variable would be used. Thought myself a clever workaround. Of course both 10 and "10" are apparently both numerical in the expression IsNumeric so therefore I never get to setting my string variable in the ELSE part of the If IsNumeric(Width.Fields("Width")) Then ............

Comment: Got my workaround to work with If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNumber (Width.Fields("Width") =True then ..... But I still don't understand why VBA is pulling Numbers stored as numbers in the worksheet as test into VBA